# SOAPUI/groovy: parameter in expanded context of response

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have following context.expand, which works correctly:

```
def response1 = context.expand( '${GetDetails#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'http://www.opentravel.org/OTA\'; //ns1:OTA_DetailsRS[1]/ns1:HotelDetails[1]/ns1:HotelDetail[2]/ns1:Code[1]}' )
```

But I want to change in last ns1:HotelDetail[2] number 2 for parameter, which I can use in cycles etc. ns1:HotelDetail[$N] is not suitable(null returns).

So, this is the point.

Sincerely,
Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strictly a Groovy problem. You can do something like:

```
def param = 2
def response1 = context.expand( '${GetDetails#Response#//*:OTA_DetailsRS/*:HotelDetails/*:HotelDetail[' + param + ']/*:Code}' )
```